# Remove trailing zeros in ggplot axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

there must surely be another way of removing trailing zeros in y axis tick labels than specifiying each label indivdiually with `labels=c("0",...)`.

I have a number of graphs plotted in a grid and there are all trailing zeros in the y axis, in particular for the zero value (see image).

[image]
If I have to set all labels in each graph manually that would be very cumbersome.

Comment: The attached image is too small to see what you refer to.

Comment: @neilfws I have rescaled the image. All zero values have trailing zeros as shown in the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding this to your `ggplot`:

```
+ scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) ifelse(x == 0, "0", x))
```

Example data:

```
data.frame(x = 1:6, 
           y = seq(0, 0.05, 0.01)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) ifelse(x == 0, "0", x))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How can I combine that with `labels = comma`?

Comment: really nice answer, however it turns 0.0001 into 1e-4

Comment: Thank you!! I have been looking to transform 1.00 into 1 but to keep 0.25!!

Comment: @Camchou [see my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77878813/1870254)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any trailing zeros, you can use `labels = scales::label_number(drop0trailing=TRUE)` in a `scale_*` function:

```r
library(ggplot2)

iris |> ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y= Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(drop0trailing=TRUE))
```

[image]

Here, I used `scales::label_number` (the `scales` package is anyway required by `ggplot2`) with the `drop0trailing=TRUE` parameter, which will be passed down to `base::format` which in turn will pass it down to `base::prettyNum` where this functionality is finally documented:
`?prettyNum`:

> **drop0trailing**
>
> logical, indicating if trailing zeros, i.e., "0" after the decimal
> mark, should be removed; also drops "e+00" in exponential formats.
> [...]

For reference, this is how the y axis labels would look by default:

```r
iris |> ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y= Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>